# how to replace selected item icon with text in bottomNavigationView or bottom appbar in android

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomappbar

I'm trying to implement this [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnkOE.jpg) in android using BottomNavigationView and I've stuck in how to replace the selected item icon with text,
I've asked my friend and he told me I can do it using a bottom appbar or using a custom layout with container view, So I've searched about bottom appbar and I didn't find how can make it behave like BottomNavigationView.

Does anyone know how to implement this design?

Thank you!